# Poi Number Cell with thousand Separator and decimal number

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am Trying to add format dynamically for thousand separator with decimal points as like below example.

pattern :- #,##0.0,#,##0.00

this works fine but when i use more than two #,##0.000 then thousand separator is not displayed in generated excel file.

Poi version is 3.11

Comment: Please show the code where you are applying the CellStyle. See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats

Comment: Try POI 3.14. There were at least 3 bug fixes related to number formats in that release (mostly 3.14 beta 1).